# After Identity Custom User , User.Identity.GetUserId() returns wrong type as string

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity-2

I created custom User model for entity framework and asp.net identity.
I checked other answers in here, they are close to my question but answers not apply my requirement. so i am asking here.

Everything is ok. 
But when i try to get user id like :

```
 ApplicationUser user = await manager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

User.Identity.GetUserId()  return string. I configured it like Guid. But it returns string :(

My classes are here.
Please help me, how can i get User.Identity.GetUserId() in a web api controller as Guid ?

```
public class GuidUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<Guid>
    {
    }


    public class GuidUserRole : IdentityUserRole<Guid>
    {
    }

    public class GuidUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<Guid>
    {
    }

    public class GuidRole : IdentityRole<Guid, GuidUserRole>
    {
    }

//public class GuidUserContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, GuidRole, Guid, GuidUserLogin, GuidUserRole, GuidUserClaim> { }
    public class GuidUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser, GuidRole, Guid, GuidUserLogin, GuidUserRole, GuidUserClaim>
    {
        public GuidUserStore(DbContext context)
            : base(context)
        {
        }
    }

    public class GuidRoleStore : RoleStore<GuidRole, Guid, GuidUserRole>
    {
        public GuidRoleStore(DbContext context)
            : base(context)
        {
        }
    }


    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid, GuidUserLogin, GuidUserRole, GuidUserClaim>, ICreateDateRequired
    {
        public ApplicationUser()
        {


        }

        [Key]
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }

        public override Guid Id { get; set; }

        public override string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }

        public string Password { get; set; }

        //Matching Attributes

        public override string Email { get; set; }
        public string FacebookId { get; set; }
        public string TwitterId { get; set; }
        public string GoogleId { get; set; }
        public override string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        public string SocialAccessToken { get; set; }

        public string Gender { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Shade> Shades { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("ParentUser")]
        public virtual List<UserFriendship> Friends { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }

        //[Column(TypeName = "DateTime2")]
        //[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }

        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        public string ThumbUrl { get; set; }
        public string BackUrl { get; set; }

        public virtual List<ContactDetail> UserContactDetails { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 11):

The definition of GetUserId is this:

```
public static string GetUserId(this IIdentity identity);
public static T GetUserId<T>(this IIdentity identity) where T : IConvertible;
```

Unfortunately Guid is not an IConvertible and it will not return the Guid type in the Generic form. Therefore, we can not use: `User.Identity.GetUserId()<Guid>` as some people use `User.Identity.GetUserId()<Int>` when they change the ID to Int.

Therefore you should use `Guid.Parse()` or `Guid.TryParse()`

```
Guid.Parse(User.Identity.GetUserId())
```

@Erik method works fine, But As I did not wanted to override the original one, I added the following general extension:

```
 public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static Guid ToGuid(this string value)
    {
        Guid result= Guid.Empty;
        Guid.TryParse(value, out result);
        return result;          
    }
}
```

and then I used this:

```
User.Identity.GetUserId().ToGuid()
```

**Edit: I came up with another solution:**

I added an extension to the Identity object.

```
public static class IdentityExtensions
{
    public static Guid GetGuidUserId(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        Guid result = Guid.Empty;
        Guid.TryParse(identity.GetUserId(), out result);
        return result;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`GetUserId()` is actually the following extension method:

```
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IdentityExtensions.GetUserId(this IIdentity identity)
```

At some point there is no way to store a value as a `Guid` (cookies!).  This means you'll have to manually change it (I just did this myself today).  What I did was moved everything that uses `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity`, `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin` and `Microsoft.Owin.Security` into a separate directory.  Then wrote my own Extension Class:

```
internal static class IIdentityExtensions
{
    public static Guid GetUserId(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        var result = Guid.Empty;

        string id = Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IdentityExtensions.GetUserId(identity);

        Guid.TryParse(id, out result);

        return result;
    }

    public static string GetUserName(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        string result = Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IdentityExtensions.GetUserName(identity);

        return result;
    }

    public static string FindFirstValue(this ClaimsIdentity identity, string claimType)
    {
        string result = Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IdentityExtensions.FindFirstValue(identity, claimType);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Just make sure you check for `Guid.Empty` (or change it to Guid?).  You'll find that there are quite a few things that just accept `string`, and you'll have to convert them.  For example:

```
namespace Microsoft.Owin.Security
{
  public static class AuthenticationManagerExtensions
  {
    public static ClaimsIdentity CreateTwoFactorRememberBrowserIdentity(
      this IAuthenticationManager manager, 
      string userId);
    public static Task<bool> TwoFactorBrowserRememberedAsync(
      this IAuthenticationManager manager, 
      string userId);
  }
}
```

So you'll have to `.GetUserId().ToString()` for certain methods to work.

Comment: But when i am trying to get Guid id in web api controller, it returns string again.  var stringResult=IdentityExtensions.GetUserId(RequestContext.Principal.Identity);

Comment: Sounds like a namespace issue, you're getting the wrong extension method.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed as you said. And now it gives error.One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

GuidUserStore: : EntityType 'GuidUserStore' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
UserStores: EntityType: EntitySet 'UserStores' is based on type 'GuidUserStore' that has no keys defined.

Comment: When i try to add a field id to GuidUserStore and create a fluent api implementation like modelBuilder.Entity<GuidUserStore>().HasKey(x => x.Id);  then it gives error when i am updating databse : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: entitySet

Comment: I decided to cancel custom id Guid type for using with identity. I am using asp.net string id field as Guid().ToString(). Finally, it works . Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

For our project, I needed to abstract the key based on `IUserKey` (and store the identifier as a `long` within this interface).

The issue with the `UserManager` heavily reliant on strings was resolved (for me) by simply overriding the `ToString()` method in the concrete implementation of the user key object.

```
public class IdentityUserKey : IIdentityUserKey
{
    public long UserId { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(IIdentityUserKey other)
    {
        return other != null && other.UserId == UserId;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return UserId.ToString();
    }
}
```

In your case, perhaps you could have wrapped `Guid` in a similar interface, and then provided the necessary `ToString()` override as well.