# aspnet - IdentityExtensions doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to extend User.Identity on controllers follow [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23621906/after-identity-custom-user-user-identity-getuserid-returns-wrong-type-as-str)

IdentityExtensions class

[image: IdentityExtensions class]

The Extension class not being applied

[image: The Extension class not apply]

Am I wrong or missing something?

Comment: you are trying to invoke extension method directly with the class name.. you have to do it with an instance of `IIdentity`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to put IdentityExtensions class near your using class with the same namespace. 
 or maybe you can show your codes , thanks.

```
namespace HelloWorldBot
{
public static class IdentityExtensions
{
    public static Guid Test(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        return Guid.Empty;
    }

    public static string GetUserId(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        return "";
    }
}

public class myController : ApiController
{
    public void Test()
    {
        var tvalue = User.Identity.Test();
    } 
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi are you trying to add a GUID for User identity table? 
I'm assuming that's what you want to achieve.

Inherit the "IdentityUser" class and add your additional fields like this.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{ 
    public Guid MyGuid { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; } 
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}
```

I think the ApplicationUser.cs is already existing on your App>Models Folder.

if not you can create one.

Hope this helps, if not can you give us more info. of what you are trying to achieve? Thanks.

Comment: read what he asks...your answer is off topic.

Comment: sorry don't follow this answer. his question was unclear 4 years ago. I guess he has the answer now.. All good..